# Why is there no (implicit) conversion from std::tuple<Ts...>& to std::tuple<Ts&...>?

Tags: c++, tuples, c++17, c++20, eastl

1. As the title states, is there a specific reason why there is no (implicit) conversion from `std::tuple<Ts...>&` to `std::tuple<Ts&...>`?
   In contrast, the `tuple` implementation of EASTL provides this conversion.

```cpp
#include <EASTL/tuple.h>

#include <tuple>

#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
  using TupleRef = std::tuple<int, float>&;
  using RefTuple = std::tuple<int&, float&>;

  using EATupleRef = eastl::tuple<int, float>&;
  using EARefTuple = eastl::tuple<int&, float&>;

  // static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<TupleRef, RefTuple>); // fails to compile
  static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<EATupleRef, EARefTuple>);

  return 0;
}
```

2. What do I have to change/add, if I reimplemented the STL `tuple` implementation?

Here is a link to godbolt show-casing the problem: https://godbolt.org/z/zqfrETKEz

PS: I used the `c++17` flag in godbolt since EASTL does not compile with the `c++20` flag, but I am also interested in a `c++20` solution.

Comment: Probably because this is quite a special case that noone working on the standard proposal that originally introduced tuples considered and because no proposal that adds this behavior has been made and/or considered important enough since.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There will be in [c++23](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b23), as a result of the `zip` paper ([P2321](https://wg21.link/p2321)).

---

Generally speaking, it is typical for overload sets to have one overload taking `T const&` and another overload taking `T&&`, it's not often that `T&` is needed as a distinct 3rd option (and `T const&&` even less so). This is one of those cases that originally had just the two, but then really does need at least the 3rd.

I'm not sure if you had a particular motivation for needing `tuple<int>&` to be convertible to `tuple<int&>`, but `zip` needs that to work, which is why it changed.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer Barry. Yes, I am implementing a `tuple_vector` container, where `value_type == tuple<Ts...>` and `reference == tuple<Ts&...>`, when usually `reference ==  value_type&`. In order to use `tuple_vector` with the `ranges` library and `views`,  `std::input_iterator<tuple_vector<Ts...>::iterator>` and then `std::indirectly_readable` has to be satisfied, so `tuple<Ts...>&` needs to be convertible to `tuple<Ts&...>` (see `std::common_reference_with`).

Comment: Is there an implementation of the `tuple` changes available somewhere Barry?